# How to do the fastest connection between twitter and discord webhook?

Tags: twitter, discord, monitor

I am new to coding and I am doing my own twitter monitor that will post all tweets from user that I set before to discord webhook. The thing I carry about the most is the delay between Tweet post time and discord webhook post time. How do you think I should do that script and what language should I learn? Does language even means when it comes to lagtime even if I set the same parameters? Do you have any tips to do it as fast as possible? Please lmk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Language doesn't matter. Your bottleneck won't be processing the tweets. The bottleneck will be waiting for the tweets to arrive.
2. Python is a beginner friendly language since it doesn't require compilation and the syntax is less strict.
3. The fastest and most consistent way of getting tweets is through the Twitter API. More specifically through the [`statuses/filter` endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter).

I happen to have a [project that does exactly what you are asking for](https://github.com/nntin/discord-twitter-bot).

Comment: The only thing worth noting here is that `statuses/filter` will be retired when the new Labs filtered stream API becomes fully production ready, but otherwise, this is useful advice.

Comment: But I've heard that twitter API has some delays on it and the best way to get extremely fast twitter monitor and to get tweets as soon as they just appear and it's possible I have to bypass API. That's what I'm asking for. I thought of using twitter scraper to this.

Comment: Might not be a good idea telling a Twitter representative that you want to scrape their website.